# ReturnToSourceQueue.exe for NServicebus on Azure

Tags: azure, nservicebus

What is the best strategy for moving messages that have been moved to the error queue back into the processing queue for nservicebus with an Azure transport configuration?

The ReturnToSourceQueue.exe only works with MSMQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Cerebrata Cloud Storage Studio](http://www.cerebrata.com/products/cloud-storage-studio/introduction) for that... but any storage explorer tool will do.

If you have a lot of messages to move, or to a lot of different queues. You'll have to create your own version of ReturnToSourceQueue.exe I'm afraid.

Kind regards,
Yves

Comment: I did not expect that it would be that simple. I guess I was under the impression that the message is contained in a "wrapped" type when placed in the error queue and that it would need to be "un-wrapped" before being placed back in the source queue so that the original message can be processed. If it is that simple moving them manually would be ok in my situation. will give it a try.

Comment: There are some additional headers to specify information about the exception and the endpoint that it came from but if you just 'drag' it back to it's original endpoint it should be processed again.

Comment: one last question on this. I am considering switching from azure storage queues to servicebus queues. how will this approach change if i make that switch? i am not sure that i will be able to use a tool like the one you mentioned as it works with storage only.

Comment: Correct, tooling is a problem for servicebus... I'm considering writing one myself next year if no one steps up.

Comment: ok thanks. i had seen this one as a possible start for tooling from way back (azure 1.5 sdk) : http://windowsazurecat.com/2011/07/exploring-topics-and-queues-by-building-a-service-bus-explorer-toolpart-1/

Comment: Tools coming from the dev teams themselves, such as this one, often don't live very long... typically they act as an example to do it yourself and MS hopes a third party steps in. Which hasn't happened thus far. There is a new sample in the Microsoft.ServiceBus SDK I believe, might serve your needs for a while.